# Optimize query to filter active IDs for a given day from big table

Tags: performance, optimization, postgresql-9.3, subquery, query-performance

I have a PostgreSQL table called `users` with 4 columns:

```
user_id   integer,       -- we can have a lot of the same user_id
name      text,          -- name of the user
value     text NOT NULL, -- enumeration values: ok, not ok, on,off
timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp NOT NULL, -- date of insertion
primary_key(user_id,name)
```

I have to select distinct `user_id` where `timestamp='date x'` and `value='on'` not having `value='off'` after. I made this query:

```
select distinct user_id,name
from users
where (timestamp='date x' and value='on')
and user_id not in (select distinct user_id from users  where value='off')
```

But it is very slow because there are more than 300K users to handle. Is there a way to make the query faster?

```
user_id name    value    timestamp
1       mike    not ok   2018-03-27 10:24
1       mike    on       2018-03-27 11:22
1       mike    ok       2018-03-27 13:33
1       mike    off      2018-03-27 15:33

2       joe     not ok   2018-03-28 10:24
2       joe     on       2018-03-28 11:22
2       joe     ok       2018-03-28 13:33
```

The result wanted is:

```
  user_id    name
    2         joe
```

because `user_id` *1* has a value `off` in the table.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid the problem here is that the condition will be just on if there is a `value=on`  but as we can have multiple same `user_id` i have to exclude where there is a `value='on' ` and `value='off'` for the same `user_id `

Comment: Given the data you provided user_id, name can't be primary key

Comment: @Lennart (user_id ,name) as primary key i mentioned it in the indexes description

Comment: Your example data does not match with your `DDL`. That's what Lennart meant.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid `(user_id,name)` this group will just be once at the table ,  for example let's take the `name='mike'` with the user_id='1' , if we will have another name='mike' it will have a different user_id (for example : user_id='1000' name='mike')

Comment: But there are 4 entries for same `name` and `id` for `mike`.. ?  and 3 entries for `joe`..??

Comment: You said `primary_key(user_id,name)` but there a multiple rows for e.g. 1 and mike in your sample data. That is what doesn't add up.

Comment: Soory guys for the uncleary things i got the point right now !! the solution that worked is when i added some indexes on the user_id with the value to speed up the searching , thanks indeed  for the collaboration guys

Comment: You mentioned *not having `value='off'` **after***. But your query excludes `user_id` with *any* `value='off'`. Is "after" relevant? Also:  300K *distinct* `user_id`? How many rows total? Is there also a table with distinct `user_id`? And is *date x* supposed to be a `date` (not a `timestamp`)? There may be much faster query styles, depending on data distribution.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , the case is that we have a set of user_id being with multiple states : `ok` `not ok` `on` `off` here we have to make sure that user_id had not the state `off` with checking that had the state `on`before , the meaning by 300k is for a user_id passing with all states , we gonna have huge data in the check part ,

Comment: @Data_Geek: I am afraid your comment does not clarify things for me. I guess there is a language barrier ...

Comment: What about the use case of a user having: ON - OFF - ON ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using an `EXISTS` as Lennart proposed, try the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX users_timestamp_value
             ON users
                (timestamp,
                 value);

CREATE INDEX users_user_id_value
             ON users
                (user_id,
                 value);
```

They should support both `WHERE`s.

See if the indexes are accepted by the optimizer by looking at the plan. And check whether they do any good.

Answer (score 1):

You could try not exists:

```
select distinct user_id 
from users u1 
where u1.timestamp='date x' 
  and u1.value='on' 
  and not exists (
      select 1
      from users u2
      where u1.user_id = u2.user_id
        and u2.value='off'
  );
```

If you want more qualified guesses, edit your question with `CREATE TABLE` statement including keys and indexes.

Comment: thanks for the collaboration , for my case is to make an optimizer selection , not a table creating , the query proposed is working but just i 'am looking for another insights if there any to optimize it :-)

Comment: probably, but it is hard to tell without knowing any details of your table

Comment: i updated my question hope that is more clear thank you for your time

Comment: Not really, what indexes are there? what type do the columns have, are they nullable or not, what does the current execution plan look like? Trying to answer your question without such details is a shot in the dark. Thats why I asked for `CREATE TABLE` statements including keys and indexes.

Comment: i added the indexes , and the table description ,thanks indeed

Answer (score 0):

If `user_id` and `name` in a 1:1 relationship, you should consider normalizing it out of this table.  In any case, rethink the choice of `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, name)`.

```
SELECT user_id
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, MAX(timestamp) AS ts
               FROM users
               WHERE value = 'ON'
               GROUP BY user_id ) AS a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT user_id, MAX(timestamp) AS ts
               FROM users
               WHERE value = 'OFF'
               GROUP BY user_id ) AS b
        ON b.user_id = a.user_id
       AND b.ts > a.ts
    WHERE b.user_id IS NULL;
```

With

```
INDEX(value, user_id, timestamp)  -- probably in this order
```